# Should the new stream lambdas be used when extracting result sets?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

A commons code to extract a result set from existing lists could be as follows:

```
List<Node> results;
for (Node node : rsp.getNodes()) {
    if (node.isValid() && node.getType == NodeType.TEST &&...) {
        if (results == null) {
            results = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        results.add(node);
    }
}
```

Now with java 8 and lambdas, as it advisable to always use streams in favor?

```
rsp.getNodes().stream.filter(node -> {
    return node.isValid() && node.getType == NodeType.TEST &&...;
}).forEach(node -> results.add(node));
```

To me, starting with java8 lately, this does not look much cleaner than the java7 code right now. Anyways you have more experience and can definitly recommend me using these type of "shortcuts" with lambdas, and not the old `foreach` style?

I know at the end it might be a matter of taste. If so, would you think my example is a totally viable case it *could* always be replaced with streams and lambdas as a good practice (I consciously did not use the term "best practice")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe separate out the conditions you're filtering on, and then you can use method references as well:

```
List<Node> results = rsp.getNodes().stream()
    .filter(Node::isValid)                      // Method reference
    .filter(n -> n.getType == NodeType.TEST)    // Lambda
    .filter(...)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());              // Produces List from Stream
```

Comment: But are there anydownsides filtering an object by multiple filter instead of a multi-condition? Anyways that's indeed a great idea I didn't see being a lambda beginner.

Comment: @membersound Which downsides are you thinking about?

Comment: Performance on large lists due to that each object is compared multiple times against each filter? Or is this probably negelectable if not having lists with a few thousands of elements?

Comment: @membersound There wouldn't be any downside. `filter()` would short-circuit similar to how `&&` does.

Comment: Why would you think each object is compared multiple times against each filter? That's not actually true.

Comment: Ok then it's indeed even better to use multiple filter in case they apply the same operation than an`&& `

Comment: But I assume, if my condition is like `a || b || c` I would have to use that complex condition inside a single filter and cannot split it?

Comment: @membersound Yes in that case you would.

Answer (score 1):

Your given case can certainly be converted to lambda (nothing wrong in that). In fact, you don't need to pre-create a list, rather use `Collectors` there:

```
List<Node> results = rsp.getNodes().stream().filter(node -> {
              return node.isValid() && node.getType == NodeType.TEST &&...;
         }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But, as your filter logic starts growing, or you start adding some more logic inside the loops or your conditions, lambda might start looking ugly. It would possibly be more readable to follow the old style `for` loops, but that would completely depend upon the scenario. You cannot generalize as to where to lambda and where to use loops.

BTW, that lambda can further be modified by avoid that explicit `return`:

```
List<Node> results = rsp.getNodes().stream()
              .filter(node -> node.isValid() && node.getType == NodeType.TEST && ...)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```